# collection for grid in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, grid, product-collection, php-7

I created a custom grid under custom tab  in product view page.

The grid was showing the total product collection from my table.

I want display the grid only current product data.

I apply filter for grid collection in magento2.

If anyone knows please explain me..

Comment: can you please add the code?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219319/customise-grid-collection-in-magento2...this is my model files

Comment: I spend lot of time in this filter.....still i'm not getting any idea about that...

Comment: what do you mean by current product data?

Comment: I'm trying initSelect() function ResoureModel/Grid/Collection file for customising grid...I can't get  current product from registry in this file..

Comment: current product means....For eg:If I'm going to product edit/view page,My grid display only particular product details....from my table collection

Comment: If u have any idea about that..